# Spring prototypes inherit properties at runtime

Tags: java, spring, dynamic, properties, prototype

What is the best approach for creating services that load a property set at runtime (bean is passed "xyz" and loads xyz.properties)? These properties files need to be able to be dropped into a folder outside the classpath before a command is entered to start the service (edit: this could happen at any time while the program is running).

I already have a system to do this that we've been using for over a year, but I'm migrating to spring to make the code more modular (customize services more easily through DI) and easier to maintain. My current method of creating an environment and then passing it with "this" to the dependencies just seems upside down from an IoC standpoint.

Is there a way to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer without hardcoding the name of the property file? Maybe just a reference to a variable I pass into the constructor of the service that its dependencies can load? So far, it looks like I will have to create a service and inject its dependencies without any config and then call a separate load method for each to pass in the properties, but that just seems like I'm not really using spring.

USE CASE: The app will pool client connections to various servers and will forward requests from other applications to these servers. New profiles must be able to be added by non-programmers without taking down or restarting the app. The profiles will include basic things like host, port, and login info, but also more complex things like whether to use tcp/http, ssl/https (which will determine which client type to use), and timeouts and pool min/max/etc (which will need default values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best approach may be to use a ServiceManager that contains the main ApplicationContext and then have each Service initialize its own FileSystemXmlApplicationContext with the main context as the parent like so:

```
public class ServiceManager {

ApplicationContext appContext;
String APP_HOME = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator;

public void init() {
    //set main spring context
    appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
}

public void start(String serviceName) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext serviceContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[]{APP_HOME + serviceName + ".xml"}, //path to child ctx
            appContext); //reference to parent ctx to build hierarchy
    Service service = (Service) serviceContext.getBean("service");
    service.start();
}
```

}

The ApplicationContext is a bit heavy to be duplicating, but memory is pretty cheap these days and this provides total separation of concerns. I still have shared logging and an event system managed by the parent context, and each service is now simplified in its own config. I built a proof of concept using two services, and it seems to work fine so far. I'll add another comment once I finish the other services and finish testing.

reference:
http://techo-ecco.com/blog/spring-application-context-hierarchy-and-contextsingletonbeanfactorylocator/

Comment: This is definitely the solution I'm going with. It may be overkill for some people, but Spring handles this very well. Everything resolves exactly as would be expected. If a class is defined in the child context (e.g. the service and its dependencies), that reference is used; otherwise, it looks in the parent context (e.g. the service manager, logger, entities, etc.). It even allows me to use each service and most dependencies as a singletons instead of prototyping. I dont see any reason to fear using multiple contexts if anyone else is in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and frankly, I couldn't wrap my head around it, somehow. It's easy enough to use when you use the existing options but I couldn't extend the framework.

So my approach was much more simple:

1. Create an annotation `@InjectConfig` which takes a config key as parameter.
2. In your beans/services, annotate fields or public setters with this annotation.
3. Write a `BeanPostProcessor` which takes options from a "config provider" and injects them into the fields / setters.
4. Now all you need is a config provider. Inject that into the post processor and you're done.

Note: I prefer annotating setters because that means you can easily configure your services from tests (just call the setters) without having to come up with smart names for 238576 config files.

**EDIT** If you have many configs, then a config factory might be a better choice:

1. Create a key to describe a config bundle (I usually use an enum or a new type here to prevent typos)
2. Put this key into the service when you create it (manually or via Spring)
3. Write a config factory that can return `Properties` or a `Map` for a config key.
4. Inject this factory into your service

In the init code of your service, use the key to lookup your config via the factory.

Using this approach, you can have a dummy factory that always returns the same thing in tests and a more complex factory for production.

The real factory can then be configured via spring so it knows where to look for configuration files. One approach is to register a `java.io.File` per config key. Now your concerns (configuring a service and loading configs) are completely separated.

Comment: interesting. this is basically how I'm already injecting the logger. This will still need some work, but at least all the custom code goes in the config provider. I'll let you know how it goes or just accept your answer if it works. thanks for the idea.

Comment: In my case, I've created a service that can overwrite the config of a bean and I'm using this service in the post processor. That way, I can reconfigure a bean at any time.

Comment: I'm still having the problem of finding a good way to pass in a name for the service to determine which properties to load. It seems like if I pass the String in the constructor, I end up resolving all the dependencies myself instead of leveraging Spring to the point where I might as well stick with my old code. Am I missing something in your answer? I'm also considering using a separate ApplicationContext for each service, and loading child contexts via spring-configs outside the classpath at runtime. any thoughts on this?

Comment: See my edits. Note that Spring isn't magic. Of course, you can achieve anything it does with plain Java as well. If Spring doesn't help, then don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input. I was already starting to put that logic in the "config provider". I can't use an enum here though. There's just too many options that need to be configured at runtime. The options can't be compiled. We're growing and adding new services so often that taking the system down to add a new one isnt feasible. I was looking at using nio.2 to scan for changes to the properties folder and add new properties as needed, but this still seems unnecessarily complex. I'm still considering using a child application context for each service. My only concern is the memory footprint

Answer (score 0):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer reads and initialize files on application context initialization and only once. So most probably you cannot configure it at runtime.
But you can have variables. For example, for my case I have default properties and user specific properties. So PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loads properties from classpath first and after that is trying to find additional properties at defined location (user home folder). I user's property file exists so configurer loads it and override properties.

Here is my example:

```
<bean id="config" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/> <!-- do not throw exception if file not found -->
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:server.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/user.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm not sure that this answer is what you're exactly need. But I'm trying to guess what is your actual task. So if you need re-read properties runtime each time you access them you have to do it manually like you did before because spring application context helps you configure your application initial configuration.

Comment: I'll edit the question with the use case. The problem with this is that properties file might not even exist when the program is started. I need to be able to add new services dynamically while the program is running.

Comment: @jasondt Ok, now I see what you need. Once I had a similar task but a little bit simpler because I new the name of the properties file and it had much simpler format but could be changed runtime. So what I did: I parametrised the path to file using _Value_ annotation and every time when property from this file was requested I read it.